# Reading Sensor data indefinitely using TCP in Swift

Tags: sockets, tcp, swift2, ios9, nsstream

I am new to Swift and i am trying to read the data from a sensor that connects to my router using Wifi. According to the sensor documentation: "In local communication mode the sensor node works as TCP/IP-server and writes output data in ASCII-format in the defined IP-address port 8080 at 1Hz rate.” So i want to read that data that the sensor is continuously emitting every second and use it to plot a chart on the iPhone. This is how the sample data looks like, the first value on each row(7255,7256.., 7259) is the time that changes every second.

7255,64,6,46,390,555,1,11137,0,0
7256,64,6,46,390,785,1,1108,0,0

7257,64,6,46,390,602,1,1135,0,0

7258,64,6,46,390,847,2,1135,0,0

7259,64,6,47,403,870,2,1669,0,0

I wrote a sample application and I am able to connect to the sensor and read the data but it doesn’t work continuously or consistently. I will receive one record then it will wait for few second and then all of a sudden i will receive the data for 5-8 seconds. Also after working for 25-30 seconds it will wait for a long time and then nothing will be read anymore. I would like to read the data continuously like the free app "WIFI TCP Test Tool" available for free on App Store. This app reads the data perfectly every second from the sensor so i know there is nothing wrong with the sensor or my router. Here is my sample code, would appreciate any help.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func readSensorData() {
        let addr = "192.168.0.100"
        let port = 8080
        var buffer = [UInt8](count: 255, repeatedValue: 0)
        var inp : NSInputStream?
        var out : NSOutputStream?

        NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName(addr, port: port, inputStream: &inp, outputStream: &out)

        if inp != nil && out != nil {
            let inputStream : NSInputStream = inp!
            inputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
            inputStream.open()
            if  inputStream.streamError == nil {
                while true {
                    let readChars: Int = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
                    if (readChars > 0) {
                        let readString: String = NSString(data: NSData(bytes:buffer, length:readChars), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
                        print(readString)
                    } else {
                        print ("sensor closed connection")
                        inputStream.close()
                        break
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print ("could not create socket")
            }
        } else {
            print("could not initialize stream")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func startSensorReadTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        readSensorData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Haven't worked with NSStream, so I can't be too helpful. However, I would recommend that you don't put an I/O operation like that on the main run loop (assuming that's what you are doing with `NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()`). That will have some effect on how timely the data is received. Otherwise, I imagine you also need to determine that it's not the sensor that is delayed in sending info. Try telnet'ing into the sensor at that address and port to verify.